# add value to different table, online doesn't working?? MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a new problem to insert a value in different table... the php give to me these errors:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home on line 8

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home on line 9

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home on line 10
```

and this is the script:

```
<?php
require 'datidatabase.php';

$uid= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['uid']);   ///LINE8
$username= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['username']); ///LINE9
$email= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['email']); ///LINE10

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $dbu, $dbp);
if (!$con){
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
        }

$db_selected= mysqli_select_db( $con,'namedatabase');
if (!$db_selected){
    die ('Can\'t use foo:' . mysqli_error());
}
//end opening connection

if(empty($uid) || empty($username)){
        echo "errore";
}else{
//artist info
        $sql="INSERT INTO TABLE1(UIDfacebook, username, email)
        VALUES
        ('$uid','$username','$email')";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql);       

        $sql1="INSERT INTO TABLE2(UIDfacebook, username)
        VALUES
        ('$uid','$username')";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

        $sql2="INSERT INTO TABLE3(UIDfacebook)
        VALUES
        ('$uid')";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

        $sql3="INSERT INTO TABLE4(UIDfacebook)
        VALUES
        ('$uid')";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql3);

        $sql4="INSERT INTO TABLE5(UIDfacebook)
        VALUES
        ('$uid')";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql4);

        echo "R.";

}
//close connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I don't know why I have this problem, I tried to edit the script a lot of time.... somebody now how I can resolve this problem?

in localhost the same script worked, I don't know what happened now... I try a lot of combination and search on internet but I didn't find anything...

Comment: **You're obviously** mixing `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*` functions, if you're getting an error like that.

Comment: Plus, when you "will" be using `mysqli_*` functions exclusively, you'll be wanting to do `$email= mysqli_escape_string($con, $_GET['email']);` instead of `$email= mysql_escape_string($_GET['email']);` --- Time for you to keep reading the tutorials.

Comment: **Code Hint:** `mysqli_ !== mysql_` --- `if(mysqli_($_IS_PRESENT_with_MYSQL_)){ it will die();}`

Comment: thank you for the answer, I corret the msql, but now I have this error in the all three of my variable: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in  -- it's really hard to understand that, I search on internet but i don't know what I can do, I start to use mysql and php this month!! thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Now, did you change all 3x where it says `mysql_escape_string($_GET...` to `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET...` (notice the added `i`) --- also is your form set to `method="get"` or `method="post"`?

Comment: yes, now I have like : $uid= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['uid']); but i don't know why the php give this error... thank you

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake earlier, and forgot that I didn't put `mysqli_real_escape_string` leaving out the `real_`

Comment: And did you change `$con = mysql_connect($host, $dbu, $dbp);` to `$con = mysqli_connect($host, $dbu, $dbp);` ? including all `mysql_` to `mysqli_` ?

Comment: if I edit the mysql connect and another mysql I will have a new error, I will edit ti first post: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home3/geribiz/public_html/apophisgame.com/giocoapp2/registrauserCOMPLETA.php on line 19

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home3/geribiz/public_html/apophisgame.com/giocoapp2/registrauserCOMPLETA.php on line 21
Can't use foo: thank you very much

Comment: Could be the way you have your DB login credentials setup in your `datidatabase.php` file. Other than that, I don't know what else to tell you to help, sorry. EDIT: I noticed you have this `require '/datidatabase.php';` using a `/` in front like that is not good. Yet, if it works, ok.

Comment: Plus, try changing this `mysqli_query($sql);` to `mysqli_query($con, $sql);` see if that one will write to DB. If so, then do the same for the other ones.

Comment: I edit the first post, and I edit the "datidatabase" for the post, maybe I need to add something in  mysqli_query? like string or something? i didn't find anything else on internet...

Comment: See my comment just above yours here. May be the problem.

Comment: I try but the problems are in my first post, I have the code in the first page, i just edit: mysqli_query($con,$sql);    , mysqli_query($con,$sql1);   ...... but the error didn't change :(

Comment: You need to also switch your `$con` in this `$db_selected= mysqli_select_db('namedatabase', $con);` to `$db_selected= mysqli_select_db($con,'namedatabase');` It's "connect FIRST", then parameters after.

Comment: I use this to get the string: test.php?uid=11111&username=test&email=test@test.com , maybe I need to change the method? thanks

Comment: I changed the $db_selected= and now I have the error in line 8,9,10 like the first post... I never use the mysqli_real_escape_string.. I need to use for one application, I use the get like this: test.php?uid=11111&username=test&email=test@test.com, but if i put just test.php? I have the same error... so, i'm wrong to use the url? thanks

Comment: That's a whole different matter. Your `id` column may need to be `INT` or `VARCHAR`. I can't help you anymore, I have to leave. You need to figure it out from hereonin, sorry.

Comment: Well, you are using $con before initialing the connection. That may be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear what's happening.  You're passing $con to the function before it was been defined. Connect first and then you'll be able to use $con in mysqli_real_escape_string.

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $dbu, $dbp);

$uid= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['uid']);   ///LINE8
$username= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['username']); ///LINE9
$email= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['email']); ///LINE10
```

Comment: thank you, now is working, but when I insert the value, it's working just for the TABLE1, if a look the database i don't have any data in TABLE2, TABLE3, TABLE4....etc do you know what is the problem? the php doesn't get error.... thank you  EDIT: I change the type of value on the database and works (for know :) ) thank you very much!!

Comment: thank you, I solve the BIG mistake, I changed different time the table and I forgot to ability the auto increment for the id... -.-' this is what happen when I stay for 11 hours on the computer... thank you everybody, this mistake made to me how make more secure the _GET!! thanks again